# I'm wondering why [sic] is used in this sentence

Tags: grammar, quotes, square-brackets, sic

I found the sentence "newapaperman's [sic] newspaper."
But I don't know the reason [sic] is used in here.
please help. Thanks.

Comment: Because it contains an error (in this case, _newspaperman_ is misspelled, missing the 's'). _Sic_ is the Latin word for 'thus; so', and editors use it to mark a mistake in a direct quotation as being present in the original text, and not introduced by the editor or printer. The square brackets are to break the narrative flow and identify the word inside as coming from the editor, not the author. One can optionally italicize _sic_ inside the brackets, or even use an exclamation point (though that's considered unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks @Lawler, I had forgotten. However I tend to think of it as an subtle insult to the *man* described. The *sic* referring to the mistake of him being described *as* a newspaperman. This under the category of: And he calls himself a newspaperman! Well, if he spells it right then perhaps he can.